# How could I fix artifacts caused by the armature modifier "Preserve volume" option

Tags: rigging, armature, weight-painting, rigify

When I'm rigging a character, I usually activate the *Preserve Volume* option on the [`Armature Modifier`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/deform/armature.html), but today I'm getting some weird artifacts with a particular part of the rig.

Example video: https://youtu.be/gfcIU6VaMmM

Note:

- I used [`Rigify`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/rigging/rigify/index.html), with a tentacle module for the ears
- I tried normalizing the weights but it only made things worse
- I need the rig to be one chain of bones so I can use dynamic bones with it
- Disabling the *Preserve Volume* is not an option since it's bad for other parts of the body

[image]

Comment: Maybe put the Multires above the Armature modifier?

Comment: there is already a multires modifier above the armature modifier, it just carry on the problem

Comment: I meant the existing Multires... what is it for by the way? Maybe share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: puting multires above only makes things worse

Comment: you didn't share the whole mesh so it's hard to tell, but why do you use a Mutlires? If it's to smooth your mesh, why don't you use a Subdivision Surface?

Comment: I shared the file, its in the post, the multires modifer is because I have displacement info on the mesh, just subdivision would make it too smooth with no detail at all

Answer (score 0):

Once I weight paint again I can get rid of what you show in your video so I think it's all a quetion of good weight painting.

See the bones that are on this bone layer, they are the ones that deform your mesh:

[image]

Select your armature, shift select the mesh, switch to *Weight Paint* mode, then select one bone after the other and look at their influence on the mesh, for each of those bones the influence goes too far, you need to correct this:

[image]

Make sure that you are in *Subtract* mode and that you can paint through (the good settings below):

[image]

Once done it seems to work fine:

[image]

Comment: the problem occurs at more "extreme" positions, when I first rigged it with automatic weights they were sharp and close to the bones, but smoothing it out actually gave better results, I think the problem is more related to the preserve volume option since the problem is completly gone with it deactivated, but as I said in the post, I can't deactivate it because of other parts of the body that need it

Comment: Once I repainted I got rid of what you show in your video so I think it's just a question of weight painting

Answer (score 0):

The main issue with quaternion skinning-- which is, in Blender, the "preserve volume" option-- is the interpolation through 180 degree rotations.  It is discontinuous.

More, it's not really whether one particular bone is at 180 degrees rotation, but whether the difference between two bones is 180 degrees.  If we have a vertex that is weighted to two, unrelated bones, and we rotate one -90 degrees in world X and the other +90 degrees in world X, that counts as 180 degrees of rotation between the bones, and quaternion skinning is going to look bad in that pose.

That means that as we have more and more weights on a single vertex, we have greater and greater risk of quaternion skinning giving us something ugly.

The first solution to the problem is to make a mesh that's in the *middle* of its likely deformations.  Use an A pose, not a T pose, for example, because then, the arms are going rotate from -45 to 45 degrees, not from 0 to 90 degrees.

The second solution is to have fewer weights on any particular vertex.  Avoid "smooth" operations on "expand", which will make weights more diffuse.  Avoid a large number of bones deep within the mesh, from which autoweights will make relatively diffuse, spread out weights.  Consider using a "limit total" operation on your weights, so that you don't have small weights from distant bones.  Give serious thought to weighting your mesh manually, so that you can ensure that, for your horn, no vertex has weights to more than 2 bones (which should be sufficient for what you're doing.)

If rendering in Blender, and you're having trouble with a particular mesh under volume preservation deformation, then one thing you can consider is using two armature modifiers, even targeting the same armature, with a vertex group to mix between one armature on volume preservation mode and another on the default blend.  For vertices that are weighted only to a single bone, there will be no difference between the two types of skinning, so loops where that's the case make the best borders for that mix.